# Indirect references to functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was just reading the book, "You don't know JS" by kyle simpson and came across the following sinppet of code that somewhat confused me. basically I was reading a topic on the `this` keyword. below is the snippet:

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;
var o = { a: 3, foo: foo };
var p = { a: 4 };
o.foo(); // 3
(p.foo = o.foo)(); // 2
```

So far reading the book I do understand how this works, but for me its hard to understand whats really happening on the last line of the snippet.

if I analysis it bymyself the last line is an iffe executing in the global scope and if in the iffe the foo() fuction executes, the this.a in the foo() function will point to the a in the global scope, which is indeed 2.

But somehow I don't feel i totally understand whats happening on the last line, can somebody break it down for me?

Thank you.

Alexander.

Comment: What's precisely missing ? The value of an assignment expression is the assigned value.

Comment: BTW this seems to be *designed* to confuse more than to teach...

Comment: The return value of an assignment is always the value itself. Therefore two steps are executed on one line. 1. `p.foo = o.foo;` 2. `foo();`

Comment: @dystroy I agree with you , but i'd appreciate an answer to my question , then a question to my question .

Comment: I agree to @dystroy for a beginners book it's written way to confusing.

Comment: In chrome I get `3, undefined` in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLpbm2rg/).

Comment: Agree with @SpencerWieczorek, In FF 31.4 I have same result : `3, undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final line is passing along the reference to the `foo` function and then executing in the global scope, just as you see.  It is equivalent to this

```
var f = p.foo = o.foo;
f();
```

Comment: when i say `(p.foo = o.foo)(); // 2`  so basically p.foo takes the value of o.foo() , and since this is an iffe, p.foo() will have to be executed in the global scope and so should print 4 i guess ?

Comment: no, the function isn't getting called during the assignment.  you are using the function as a variable.  so after this operation p.foo and o.foo both reference the defined method foo() in the global scope.  The assignment doesn't actually call the method.  Assignments return the value being assigned so you can do `c = (a = b)` and everything will equal `c`.  Since the thing being assigned is the foo function, that is what gets called at the end.

Comment: if c represents foo() in ur example , where in this line . `(p.foo = o.foo)(); // 2` am i calling foo explicitly .

Comment: the final `()` calls the result of the assignment, which is foo

Answer (score 3):

The return value of an assignment is always the value itself. At this example the return value is a reference to the function *foo*. Therefore two steps are executed on one line.

1. `p.foo = o.foo;`
2. `foo();`

Answer (score 1):

This is whats happening:

when `(p.foo = o.foo)();` is called, JS transforms it into

```
function foo() {
  console.log( this.a );
}
```

and since `var a = 2` is set in the global scope, and nothing is passed to the function, your result is `2`

So then the question is why does JS transform `(p.foo = o.foo)` into the `foo()` function?

well if you break it down, you have this:

`p.foo = o.foo` : this is assigning the variable from right to left. Just like `var a = "something";` so this means that now, `p.foo` equals `o.foo`, and since `o.foo` equals `foo`, we are now saying `p.foo = foo`, in other words this:
`(p.foo = o.foo)();` is the same as `(foo)()` which then runs the `foo` function.

To further explain:

```
 console.log(p.foo); //returns undefined because nothing was set to it
 console.log(o.foo); //returns foo, because it was assigned var o = {foo: foo};
 p.foo = o.foo; // this assignes foo to p.foo
 console.log(p.foo); //returns foo, it is no longer undefined, because of our assignment
 (p.foo)(); // will run the function
```

---

I had problems with getting `undefined` before, but that was because I was running tests on http://jsfiddle.net/ which prevented me from accessing my function correctly.